# Metrizable topological space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Why Extended real numbers set with T ( T topology on R with infinity) , is metrizable ? And how can prove that d(x,y) genetares this topology (T) ??

Comment: i don't understand to which metric $d$ are you referring. and it is not clear what topology are you using. i assume you mean that $T$ is the one point compactification? if thats the case you can use Urysohn's metrization theorem.

Comment: @sha d(x,y)=| arctanx - arctany |

Comment: @sha the topology (T) is : the  empty set belongs to (T) the extended real numbers set belongs to (T) and if (x) belongs to (A) and (A) belongs to (T) then there is (s>0) such that the interval (x-s,x+s) is contained in (A) if (x) belongs to (A) and (x= positive infinity ) then there is (a>0) such that the interval ]a,+infinity] is contained in (A) if (x) belongs to (A) and (x= Negative infinity ) then there is (b<0) such that the interval [-infinity ,b[ is contained in (A)

Answer (score 1):

The main idea here is simply that the topology $\mathcal{T}$ of the extended reals $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is in fact the order topology (generated by "intervals"), and the proposed metric $d$ respects the order, that is, the open balls with respect to $d$ correspond to those "intervals".

First of all for the definition of $d(x,y)=|\arctan x-\arctan y|$ to make sense on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, we have to extend the definition of $\arctan$ to $\pm\infty$. The natural extension is $\arctan(\pm\infty)=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$. It is then routine to check that $d$ is a metric.

Clearly $\mathcal{T}$ has as basis $\mathcal{B}$ the *intervals*, that is, the union of $\{(a,b)|a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ (type [I]), $\{\{-\infty\}\cup(-\infty,a)|a\in\mathbb{R}\}$ (type [II]), and $\{(b,\infty)\cup\{\infty\}|a\in\mathbb{R}\}$ (type [III]). Hence it suffices to show that every $B\in\mathcal{B}$ is an open ball with respect to $d$, and conversely every open ball with respect to $d$ is a union of elements in $\mathcal{B}$ (or, more directly, *is* an element of $\mathcal{B}$, if we include the rays $(-\infty,a)$ and $(b,\infty)$ in $\mathcal{B}$).

- A basis set of type [I] is an open ball centered at $\tan\left(\dfrac{\arctan b+\arctan a}{2}\right)$ of radius $\dfrac{\arctan b-\arctan a}{2}$.
- A basis set of type [II] is an open ball of radius centered at $-\infty$ of radius $\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan a$.
- A basis set of type [III] is an open ball of radius centered at $\infty$ of radius $\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan b$.

The converse is easy to check by even more cumbersome to write.